# Keeping track of client logged-in OS user when connecting to a database server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, audit

We are implementing a monitoring solution that keeps track of logins to SQL Server.

We need to capture the following event: a user logs in to a Windows client and from there logins to a remote SQL Server using SQL Authentication.

When this occurs, we need to keep track of the Window user that logged into the Windows client.

Is there any chance to configure SSMS to pass the credentials of currently logged-in Windows user to the SQL Server it is connecting to?

Comment: Use Windows Authentication maybe?

Comment: @Charlieface most of users use Windows Authentication. Unfortunately a small quota of users must keep using SQL authentication, so we must support it.

Comment: Then no you can't. There is no other mechanism for passing it through (other than maybe doing a manual `EXEC sp_set_session_context` at the top of every script)

Comment: Even Windows Authentication isn't perfect here either. `Domain\UserA` can login to a Windows machine, then run SSMS as a different domain user, `Domain\UserB`, and then connect to SQL Server. The SQL Server instance would only see `UserB` and have no way to tell the user logged into the Windows machine is `UserA`. Basically, there's no reliable way to do this.

Comment: @J.D. They can only do that if they Impersonate, in which case they *are* the other user. It's an unusual setup, either way.

Comment: @Charlieface Impersonate?...that's not what I'm referring to. Anyone logged into a Windows machine can right click on the SSMS icon while holding the Shift key and then have the option to run SSMS "*...as a different user*". I do it regularly to connect to my SQL instances as an admin account provisioned to me specifically, but I don't use that same admin account to actually login to my machine with. I can envision other scenarios too such as shared workstations that are constantly logged in as a separate generic user from those who run the apps on it. I've seen that one done elsewhere lol.

Comment: @J.D. That's is exactly what impersonation is, `Run as a different user`, it's just you are impersonating using an interactive login rather than programmatically. AFAIK it's not common to want to know who the *impersonating* user is. Normally once you impersonate then you *are* that user for all intents and purposes.

Comment: @Charlieface ah, client level impersonation, fair enough. Never really thought it through, but yea I guess that's what SSMS is doing in that case. Sorry, when I hear impersonate these days, I think of the `EXECUTE AS` impersonation within SQL Server.

Comment: @J.D. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/impersonation

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use client_net_address, in sys.dm_exec_connections, to query the AD to see who is logged in at that IP.

Comment: This sounds quite interesting idea. Which AD attributes / whatever should one look up in order to map a host with login?

Comment: Bit useless if everyone is behind NAT on the same address. And it only tells you the IP address, not the username, there may be multiple users using that machine.